# Cant Remove Nut on Clutch

Tags: honda, motorcycle, clutch, repair, nut

I have a 2006 Honda crf150F. I need to get to the components of my shifter to adjust something, but I need to remove the entire clutch housing to get to it.

Here is a drawing of the clutch assembly: http://www.bikebandit.com/oem-parts/2006-honda-crf150f/o/m15655?a=11#sch415323

I need to remove part 12 to get the housing off.

To get to part 12 I need to remove 8, 4 11s, and 4 10s. At this point there is no pressure on the friction plates so when I try to remove 12 I just rotate whatever shaft is connected to the drive train and to the rear wheel(does not turn the part of the clutch with the gear meshing with the engine gear) and I have no way of stopping the rotation firmly enough to break whatever is holding in the nut so tightly.

I called the dealer and even they don't have a tool for this... 
Does anybody know anything I can try to get this off? At this point it seems like my only option is to make something custom and costly which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Try an impact wrench.  Sometimes the quick taps will be able to jar the bolt loose.

Comment: @cullub I tried my impact wrench(with a full compressor) with my beefy friend holding the tire as hard as he could. No dice

Comment: [Here are some pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=clutch+holder&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV0rSov9rNAhUi5YMKHY28CbYQ_AUICSgC&biw=1920&bih=948) of clutch holding tools, some of them homemade - you could try something like that.

Comment: Although if it's still connected to the transmission (and the tires), you could maybe chain the tires somehow

Comment: I'll stop by a hardware store and find something metal I can drill 4 holes into to hold it in place like some people in those pictures.. I'll let you know if it works

Comment: Cool.  I had this same problem a few weeks ago, but I didn't have an impact wrench at the time, so the constant pressure broke the clutch assembly.  I'd suggest using the impact wrench when you get the holder made.

Comment: Interesting. I was more concerned about the jarring of the gears than the constant pressure of a ratchet... but ill be careful. thanks

Comment: If the transmission is in gear, ensure you are doing it in the highest gear possible. This will give whomever is holding the wheel the most torque advantage and should allow you to spring this with an impact wrench. Also ensure you are using impact sockets to do it. I've recently found out you use these not for their toughness, but for the sheer fact of mass which works wonders.

Comment: @nick  Any chance of getting a pic of what you are challenged with.  The parts explosion is helpful but a picture says a thousand words.

Answer (score 2):

**You need a clutch basket removal tool**

This tool will allow the inner and outer clutch basket to become locked together in order for you to remove the bolt that is affixed to your transmission primary shaft.

[image]

This is a relatively cheap tool.  I recommend you use an air impact to remove the bolt.  Upon tightening you will want to use a torque wrench and lock your crankshaft on the stator side with a wrench.

[**Here are some selections to source the tool from.**](https://www.google.com/search?q=motion%20pro%20clutch%20basket%20removal%20tool&biw=1280&bih=653&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUnvu5t-DNAhXCdj4KHRPvA9oQ_AUIBygA&dpr=1.5#q=clutch%20basket%20removal%20tool)

Comment: please take a quick look at the drawing I linked. I cant use this tool because of the way my clutch is made, the plates are all still trapped inside

Comment: I think your best bet is to take a pic to truly illustrate your issue.  If you do I am optimistic we can assist you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know of to remove a bolt like this is to use a ratchet with (preferably) an impact 6 point socket.  Put it on the bolt and hit the ratchet with a large hammer. One or two good solid hits will often times break it loose. You can also hit the head of the bolt with the hammer, just a couple of taps, not hard swings can also help loosen it. Do NOT use a wrench. A ratchet will bounce back and spin if the bolt doesn't come loose. A wrench will fly accross the room and hurt someone or something. It may take several hits but it usually works. Honda crankshaft pulley bolts won't come loose with an impact but will come loose this way. Let me know what works!